Samsung j5 won't charge
I have a Samsung J5 that I got from a friend. But I have a problem with it,

The back and recent buttons don't work
The charging port makes the phone's screen flicker and it isn't even charging (it only charges if it is turned off completely, no charging icon)
The flashlight is on but very dim, I can't use it even if the phone is powered off it is glowing.

Can anyone help?

Sorry, but that sounds like a hardware problem that needs replacement parts... That is nothing we can help you with.
